# .htaccess setting error_display to E_ALL

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I understand I can set error_display within .htaccess file using predefined constants: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

I am looking for a number that would let me set the error_display to all but disable strict mode, warnings and notices

I guess the equivalent of E_ALL | ~E_WARNINGS | ~E_NOTICES | ~E_STRICT ?

Comment: Replace the `|` with `&` in that statement and you should have what you need.

Comment: That's the `error_reporting` setting (which goes to the log).  There's a separate setting for `display_errors`, a boolean determining whether to send those errors to the browser.  You cannot separate the error levels displayed vs logged though, probably without coding a custom error handler.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PHP constants, this would equate to: 32767 & ~2 & ~8 & ~2048 which is 30709 (according to my Windows programmer's calculator)

```
# in your .htaccess file...
php_value error_reporting 30709
```

Comment: thank you. But I am still getting strict error display "Strict Standards: Non-static methodl anguageManager::loadModuleLanguage() should not be ..." is there another number I can use? Thank you